# Time between arrivals Distribution

Tags: queueing-theory, poisson-distribution, simulation

I am simulating a hair parlor queue with m number of queues and 3 different types of services (queues).
I was doing the time between arrival with a uniform distribution with a min value and a max value and a random, however a friend told me that i should use poisson distribution,(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

Then I read some theory in the Discrete Event Simulation book of JBanks and online almost every one use the poisson distribution I understand that you need x time in order to know the probability number of customers arriving in that time however is not suitable for me asking each time because is a does simulation the clock change.

What distribution should i use or what can i do for the time between arrivals?

Example tba: time between arrival , at: arrival time

1. customer:1 tba:0.5 clock:0.0 at:0.5
2. customer:2 tba:1.0 clock:0.5 at:1.5
3. customer:3 tba:3.0 clock:0.5 at:4.5

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that customers arrive at a constant rate $\lambda$, then the Poisson distribution is  distribution of the number of customers arrived at a time $t$:
$$P_t(n)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}.$$

The distribution of time to wait before a customer arrives is exponentially distributed :
$$p(t)=\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}.$$
**Edit** This is the answer to your question. The waiting time between two arrivals of customers is exponentially distributed.

**Proof**

At $t=0$, we have $P_0(0)=1$ and $P_n(0)=0$ for $n\geq1$.

Suppose that we have $n+1$ customer arrived at time $t+\mathrm dt$. What has happened since time $t$ ? We have two possibilities: either a new customer as arrived (so there were only $n$ customer at time $t$) or not. This is summed up into this equation
$$P_{n+1}(t+\mathrm dt)=P_n(t)P_1(\mathrm dt)+P_{n+1}(t)P_0(\mathrm dt).$$
Let us expand to the first order in $\mathrm dt$ to get
$$ P_{n+1}(t)+\partial_tP_{n+1}(t)\mathrm dt=P_n(t)P_1(\mathrm dt)+P_{n+1}(t)P_0(\mathrm dt).\tag{1}$$

According to the assumption that the rate of arrival $\lambda$ is constant 
the probability to have one customer arriving after a short time $\mathrm dt$ is
$$P_1(\mathrm dt)=\lambda\mathrm dt.$$
 We conclude that $P_0(\mathrm dt)=1-\lambda\mathrm dt$.

Plugging this into equation (1), we obtain immmediately for $n\geq0$
$$\partial_t P_{n+1}(t)=\lambda\left(P_n(t)-P_{n+1}(t)\right).\tag{2}$$
and for $P_0$ we have $$\partial_tP_0(t)=-\lambda P_0(t).$$
We obtain then that $P_0(t)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}$.
The time distribution for the waiting time between two arrivals is the same as the time distribution of the first arrival, so this is given by
$$p(t)=\partial_t(-P_0(t))=\lambda\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}$$
as announced.
Solving the equations (2) by induction yields the distribution of the number
of customer at time $t$. As we have seen the induction is proven for $n=0$.
Let us assume $P_n(t)=\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}$.
The using (2) we have
$$\partial_tP_{n+1}(t)=\lambda\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}-
\lambda P_{n+1}(t)$$
The solution of this first order ordinary differential equation is standard.
We get
$$P_{n+1}(t)=\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}\int_0^t\mathrm e^{\lambda u}\lambda\frac{(\lambda u)^n}{n!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda u}\mathrm du=\frac{(\lambda t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\mathrm e^{-\lambda t}.$$
And we have proven the statement.

Comment: This will be valid with an finite queue population?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by finite queue population.

Comment: Reading again your question, I think my answer provides the answer you asked for. The time between two arrivals is distributed according to $p(t)$, this is the standard assumption for waiting queues. If you have more than one queue it is equivalent to have separate waiting times (one for each queue) or a single waiting time and a random choice at arrival.